# How to make my model read from files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I got my data stored in files in tab separated text format. I would like my model to read them instad of loading data from DB. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but not recommended. Why don't you just import your data into a database? That would be much easier.

Comment: What's with the files out of interest? Agree with @Mischa on that..

Comment: I'm processing text files (e.g. extract NE, POS, etc.) that why things need to be at text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that document_mapper should be worth looking at: https://github.com/ralph/document_mapper